# Как правильно написать MVC роутер?

Tags: php, mvc

Всем привет. Сделал небольшую MVC. Все контроллеры,модели и виды работают так как надо. Единственное точка входа-очень кривовата. Если кто-то может подсказать как можно сделать еще без require/require_once(Просто какое-то колдовство-с этими require никак не работает). 
Конструктор ParseUrl не обрабатывает require/require_once/include , хотя файл существует. Через run1 все работает , но , на мой взгляд , это топорный метод.
Код

```
index.php 

    <?php
    namespace ProductReview;

    require_once 'vendor/autoload.php';

    $obj = new ParseUrl();
    $obj->run1();
```

ParseUrl.php

```
 class ParseUrl
{

    protected $controller = 'ProductController.php';

    protected $method = 'index';

    protected $params = 'name';


    public function __construct()
    {
        $url = $this->getRoute();
        $controller = ucfirst($url[1] . 'Controller.php');
        print $controller;
        print '<br>';
        print 'Controllers/' . $controller;
        print '<br>';
        if (file_exists(__DIR__ . '/Controllers/' . $controller)) {
            $this->controller = $controller;
            print 'yes';
        } else {
            print 'No';
        }
        print '<br>';
        print __DIR__ . '/Controllers/' . $this->controller;
        require_once 'Controllers/' . $this->controller;

        new $this->controller;
        print_r($this->controller);
    }

    public function getRoute()
    {
//        $uri = explode('/', filter_var(rtrim($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']), FILTER_SANITIZE_URL));
        $uri = $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];
        return $uri;
    }

    public function run1()
    {
        switch ($this->getRoute()) {
            case '/':
                {
                    $obj = new ProductController();
                    $obj->index();
                    break;
                }
            case '/test':
                {
                    $obj = new ProductController();
                    $obj->test1('name');
                    break;
                }
            case '/show':
                {
                    $obj = new ProductController();
                    $obj->show();
                    break;
                }
            case '/form':
                {
                    $obj = new ProductController();
                    $obj->create();
                    break;
                }
            case '/store':
                {
                    $obj = new ProductController();
                    $obj->store($_POST);
                    $obj->index();
                    break;
                }
            case'/reviews':
                {
                    $obj = new ReviewController();
                    $obj->index();
                    break;
                }
            case '/sort/' . $this->params:
                {
                    $obj = new ProductController();
                    $obj->sort($this->params);
                }

            case '/sort/' . $this->params:
                {
                    $obj = new ProductController();
                    $obj->sortDesc($this->params);
                }
            default :
                {
                    $obj = new ProductController();
                    $obj->notFound();
                    break;
                }

        }

    }
```

Comment: Через include попробуйте

Comment: Пробую - выдает ту же ошибку Uncaught Error: Class 'ProductController.php' not found in

Comment: Так у Вас проблема не в инструкциях - пути не соответствуют, раз не находит - а лишних пробелов перед объявлением namespace  нет случайно?

Comment: Вы наверное меня не поняли - этот код полностью рабочий . При переходе /test отрабатывает ProductController@test и т.д.. Просто до этого я писал   $url = $this->getRoute(); $controller = ucfirst($url[1] . 'Controller.php');if (file_exists(__DIR__ . '/Controllers/' . $controller)) $this->controller = $controller; require_once 'Controllers/' . $this->controller;  и require не отрабатывал. Я подумал, может есть способ написать без них

Comment: Ну, теперь вопрос разъяснен и и разобраться знающему будет проще - возможно, стоит это разъяснение добавить в само тело вопроса.

Comment: Ваш код не лучшего качества. Это не роутер, а велосипед с костылями. Посмотрите лучше это https://elisdn.ru/blog/114/psr7-framework-router

Answer (score 2, accepted):

я проект ваш не в корне сделал а во вложенной папке, так что учитывайте этот нюанс глядя код ниже.

начну с композера
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

дальше ваш индекс

```
<?php

//namespace ProductReview;

use App\ParseUrl;
use Mpakfm\Printu;

require_once 'vendor/autoload.php';

$obj = new ParseUrl();

// Это вместо print_r - не обращаем внимания
Printu::log($obj, '$obj');
```

Вызвали парсер и все.
Теперь посмотрим на парсер

```
namespace App;

use Mpakfm\Printu;

class ParseUrl {

    protected $controller = 'App\\Controller\\ProductController';

    public function __construct() {
        $url = $this->getRoute();
        //$controller = ucfirst($url[1] . 'Controller.php');
        $controller = 'App\\Controller\\' . ucfirst($url) . 'Controller';

        Printu::log($url, '$url');
        Printu::log($controller, 'controller');

        try {
            $res = new $controller();
        } catch (\Throwable $exception) {
            Printu::log($exception->getMessage(), 'exception');
            $controller = $this->controller;
            Printu::log($controller, 'default controller');
            $res = new $controller();
        }
        Printu::log($res, 'call controller');
        return;
    }

    public function getRoute() {
        //        $uri = explode('/', filter_var(rtrim($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']), FILTER_SANITIZE_URL));
        $uri = $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];
        // для теста беру путь с GET
        if (isset($_GET['page'])) {
            return $_GET['page'];
        }
        return 'product';
    }
```

Итак что мы делаем, заставляем работать композер вместо нас. У нас есть подключенный к автозагрузчику каталог lib как точка вхождения для namespace App
дальше по прав илам psr-4 Контроллер помещаем в соотв папку и делаем там соотв имя и неймспейс:

```
namespace App\Controller;

use Mpakfm\Printu;

class ProductController {

    public function __construct() {
        Printu::log(true, 'ProductController');
    }
}
```

Все, теперь парсер получает имя из урла, пристыковывает ему неймспес до контроллеров, делает первую букву большой и вконце дописывает Controller:
$controller = 'App\Controller\' . ucfirst($url) . 'Controller';

После остается только запустить и композер сам найдет этот контроллер, если он есть. Если нет - подсунем контроллер по умолчанию и запустим его. Так же запустим через автолоадер композера.

вывод на экран для индекса:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

и для какой-либо страницы где контроллер не нашелся:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

PS: На всякий случай, после любых изменений файла composer.json нужно в консоли исполнять "composer update", что бы эти изменения применились.

Answer (score 0):

Проблема не с require, а со строкой `new $this->controller` . В свойство $this->controller установлено значение `ProductController.php` - файл с таким именем существует, он подключён, класса с таким именем нету. Тут либо сразу пропишите `protected $controller = 'ProductController'`, а при реквайре допишите расширение `.php`, либо обрезайте расширение при вызове `new $this->controller`.